# Boostrap Ajax Tabs with a twist

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggeling to get the following result. A user browses through the tabs but he doesn't see the loading effect when reentering the same page (well this is because the default value is overrided by the loader) - but how can I override the .load() DOM with loader on a non active tab [ simplification :: clear the content when leaving the tab] .

My basic attempt. The first tab doesn't work when reentering from ajax pages, but that it's not the case it runs normally on my page.

TLDR - Replace content to original content(loader) after leaving the active tab

Simple JQuery

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajaxSetup({
    'cache': true
  });
  var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
  var href = this.hash;
  var pane = $(this);
  $(href).load(url, function(result) {
    pane.tab('show');

  });
});
```

And a example

https://jsfiddle.net/074rk3re/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax Boostrap Tabs [Admin LTE template] with state save

Ok I figured it out :) Posting in case someone will need it usefull too. Please also rebuild my question if needed.

Starting off

I used this two variables to keep the track of the clicked tab and the previous tab to clear the DOM with a loader

```
var targetel = $(e.target).filter($(this).attr('href'));
var prevel = $(e.relatedTarget).filter($(this).attr('href'));
```

Next I added a short sleep for the ajax call. [ A Todo perhaps : while toggeling the tabs fastly like tree times on each they doesn't cancel the load, it will be loaded with a xhr request later which is kinda pointless, you got any idea how to prevent this? ]

Then I added the loader element. Since on first load there is no previous element there needs to be a condition. Not sure if its a proper way to context this but it works.

```
 $(targ).html('<div class="overlay text-center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></div>');
  if (prevel.context) {
    $(prevel.context.hash).html('<div class="overlay text-center"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-5x"></i></div>');
  }
```

Also fancy staff, that I didn't posted as a question is the state save of the active tab after refreshing the browser. I force a click - since it's xhr content so I guess only option, and save it to localStorage. This state save will work after you choose a tab. By default there is no selection if you want to have so you could do something like this

```
$('#myTabs > li > a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').trigger('click');
```

where activeTab would be the ID of the link in `<li>`.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if (activeTab) {
  $('#myTabs > li > a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').trigger('click');
}
```

That's all, if you got any suggestions please write.

Full code available here

https://jsfiddle.net/074rk3re/9/